# Using CommandParameters and MultiBindings?

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid

Is it possible to use CommandParameter="{Binding}" in a multi binding?
I am trying to do this in a data grid.

```
<CheckBox.CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CDetailConverter}">
        <Binding Path ="IsChecked" ElementName="chkSelection"/>                                        
        <Binding ConverterParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</CheckBox.CommandParameter>
```

The second Binding throws an error.

Comment: Converter parameter is not a Dependency property so you cannot `Bind` something to it.... what are you trying to do any way ??

Comment: Protip:  No need to put tags in titles, and "throws an error" is practically useless without the actual exception type and message.  In this case, you were lucky that the whole converter requirement for multibinding command parameters is well known.  In future, it may result in you not getting any answers to your questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, the answer is no.

In your second inner `Binding` you have set `ConverterParameter`. There are a couple of problems with this:

First, `Binding` is its own class separate from `MultiBinding` with both `Converter` and `ConverterParameter` properties. Here you have set the `ConverterParameter` property without setting the `Converter` property. Remember that `ConverterParameter` is passed to the `Binding's` specified converter regardless if it is used within a `MultiBinding` or not. If you were to add a `Converter` here, then the converter would be passed the specified `ConverterParameter`.

What you probably meant to do was set the `ConverterParameter` on the outer `MultiBinding` which also has this property:

```
<CheckBox.CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CDetailConverter}" ConverterParameter="{Binding }">
        <Binding Path ="IsChecked" ElementName="chkSelection"/>                                        
    </MultiBinding>
</CheckBox.CommandParameter>
```

If you try this, you will quickly see that `ConverterParameter` can not be the target of a `Binding` expression since it is not a `DependencyProperty`.

Since you can not bind to `CommandParameter`, the typical workaround is to modify your `IMultiConverter` to accept an additional value, and supply this value through a binding expression:

```
<CheckBox.CommandParameter>
    <!-- CDetailConverter updated to expect an additional value in the values array -->
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CDetailConverter}">
        <Binding Path ="IsChecked" ElementName="chkSelection"/>
        <Binding />                                   
    </MultiBinding>
</CheckBox.CommandParameter>
```

Hope this helps!